# WCF SOAP missing xsi:type (consumed by PHP SoapClient)

Tags: php, .net, wcf, soap, soap-client

I have WCF SOAP service. When this service is consumed by .NET app all is OK. When I consume this service from PHP SoapClient, all returned values are interpreted as string. Types are defined in WSDL. It completely ignores them.

My response is:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <EmployeeCountResponse xmlns="some namespace">
         <EmployeeCountResult>569</EmployeeCountResult>
      </EmployeeCountResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I imagine something like (notice `xsi:type="xsd:int"`):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <EmployeeCountResponse xmlns="some namespace">
         <EmployeeCountResult xsi:type="xsd:int">569</EmployeeCountResult>
      </EmployeeCountResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

In WSDL there is:

```
<xs:element name="EmployeeCountResponse">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EmployeeCountResult" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Also when I generate request in SoapUI there are no xsi:type defined on elements. Is there a way to add there attributes to elements, or to force other clients read this information from `?singlewsdl` ?

PHP code:

```
       $client = new SoapClient('someurl?singlewsdl',
        array(
                "stream_context" =>
                        stream_context_create(array("http"=>array(
                                "header"=> "ApiKey: somekey"
                        ))),
                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                'exceptions' => true,
                'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
                "trace" => true
        )
);

try
{
    $params = ['someparam' => 'somevalue'];
    $resp = $client->employeeCount($params);
}
catch (SoapFault $exception)
{
    echo($exception->getCode());
}
```

PHP sees returedd int as string and also when WCF throw an exception with faultcode, PHP is unable to read it and `$exception->getCode()` returns '0'.

Comment: Please add the PHP code in question.

Comment: The WSDL defines EmployeeCountResult as a string, so PHP is correctly returning a string.  The type does not have to be specified in the response, as it id defined in the WSDL.  Were you expecting an integer?

Comment: Sry, my bad. There should be int in question of course. I've edited it.

Comment: @nCrazed - I have added PHP code